# Replacing a sagging/rusting stucco steel mesh ceiling below a deck steel floor

Tags: outdoor, exterior, stucco, porch

I have a 1st floor porch ceiling that is separating and rusting that I need to tear down and replace.  It's a steel porch with tile floors and what I'm guessing is some sort of corrugated galvanized steel deck.

My question is once I tear down the stucco steel mesh and wire brush the rust off, what do I replace it with?  What is this stucco steel mesh thing called and is it normally used for exterior work under a porch?

If I do some sort of stucco mesh sheet replacement, will it just trap water and sag again?  Should I just paint the wavy steel underneath and not put a replacement up, showing unpainted ribbed steel like my neighbors?  If I don't replace it with some sort of painted stucco it won't match the 2nd-floor porch above it, but I'm also worried I'll run into the same problem again.  It's tile floor on top - do I need to redo or reseal the tiles?  I don't notice any obvious holes or cracks in the tiles above the ceiling.

What is the recommended way to refinish it - leave it bare or use some sort of coating/paint/covering?  If that's galvanized steel underneath, paint won't stick to it correct?  In that case if I wirebrush the rust transfer off, I might scrape the galvanized layer off in which case I'd have to treat that area?  Or maybe there is a gentler way of removing the rust residue without scraping the galvanized coating?  Is it a safe guess to assume that it's galvanized deck, or is there some steel deck that's not galvanized?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It is my (possibly incorrect) understanding that the corrugated steel you're seeing is _basically_ the form into which the concrete floor is poured. It does provide long-term additional support for the concrete, as well, so maintenance is necessary. I would suggest removing whatever stucco-like covering is over it, wire-brushing it to remove the heavy rust, coating it with a rust converter which will chemically alter the iron oxide to prevent further rusting, then primer & paint for protection. This will require annual review to ensure it's not rusting further, [con't]

Comment: and maintenance if/when it does show signs of additional rusting. I'm posting as a comment because I have enough confidence to do this on my house (if I had this situation), but not enough to _truly_ encourage someone else to do so. Wait for further confirmation...